# how can append data in url for ActionResult Method using window.location.href =

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

i cant understand how bring data using `window.location.href = '/Product/Success/'+data.OrderTrackNo+'';` i can bring data using ajax but it is some thing difference bringing data with `window.location.href`, so i can't

my jquery code is

```
 var cartid = $("#userid").text();
                var email = $('#youremail').val();
                var name = $("#yourname").val();
                var phoneno = $("#yourphoneno").val();
                var ship = $("#thtshipinfo").val();
                var pin = $("#txtpin").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Product/cartSave',
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { 'cartid': cartid, 'name': name, 'email': email, 'phoneno': phoneno, 'Address': ship, 'pin': pin },
                    success: function (data) {

                        alertify(data.OrderTrackNo);
                        window.location.href = '/Product/Success/'+data.OrderTrackNo+'';

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(Error);
                    }
                })
```

and Actionresult code is

```
  public ActionResult success( int orderno)
    {
        DeliveryLocationCookies();
        loginMaintain();
        cartMaintain();
        ViewBag.orderno = orderno;
        return View();

    }
```

this actionresult within Product controller

Comment: What problem are you having? What is the value of `data.OrderTrackNo`? And what is the point of using ajax if all you do is redirect?

Comment: `data.OrderTrackNo` ajax callback data  in this case ajax **success** block bring some data and this data i save in `data.OrderTrackNo` variable. and after that agan redirect using `window.location.href = '/Product/Success/'+data.OrderTrackNo+'';`

Comment: Yes, but what is your problem? And do you have a route defined for `Product/Success/{orderno}`? But using ajax to call a method and then redirect in the success callback is just pointless. Make a normal submit and redirect in the POST method.

Comment: as @StephenMuecke was saying just redirect and do the error checking on the server side, it's the same ... if not better as you will be doing only one request instead of two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the variable name on your query string like this:

```
window.location.href = "/Product/Success/?orderno=" + data.OrderTrackNo;
```